# Text of Password type InputField only gets asterisks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a login system in Unity. It connects to a mysql backend via php, so I am using the WWWForm. The password field has the content type set to password, so it will mask the input from the user. I want to send the actual value of the field not the masked value.

I've tried PasswordField.text, but that only sends the masked version. After some research, it was suggested to use .value, only the editor highlighted that in red. A little stumped here, please help.

```
public string UsernameField;
public string PasswordField;
public string LocationField;

public Text UserText;
public Text PasswordText;
public Text LocationText;

public InputField PasswordInput;

public void UserLogin()
{
    StartCoroutine ("LogintheUser");
}


public IEnumerator LogintheUser()
{
    UsernameField = UserText.text;
    LocationField = LocationText.text;
    PasswordField = PasswordText.text.value;
    Debug.Log (UsernameField);
    Debug.Log (LocationField);
    Debug.Log (PasswordField);
```

The only error came from php indicated the wrong password was entered, when I know I typed it correctly.

Comment: I tested inputField.text, and it works even with the password content type. I think you have a different problem. Maybe you're not reading the correct UI element? It looks like you should be doing `PasswordField = PasswordInput.text;` instead of `PasswordField = PasswordText.text;`

Comment: That is the problem precisely. Yet when I use PasswordText.text, it sends the masked password.

Comment: @KenGordon they're saying to use `PasswordField = PasswordInput.text;`

Comment: i had that problem a few years ago, it was really tricky to find out how to solve the problem, sometimes the unity documentation is very confusing.

Comment: @Nicolas I agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use `PasswordField = PasswordInput.text;`

From the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html) on `InputField`:

> To obtain the text of the Input Field, use the text property on the InputField component itself, not the text property of the Text component that displays the text. **The text property of the Text component may be cropped or may consist of asterisks for passwords**.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!